# Possibility of script to recognize you are logged in on another server?

Tags: php

So, if you are logged in on one server is there a script you can use that will alert the other server (same domain, different server) and make a basic change to the html based upon the fact that you are logged in. The html change could be, for example you are now logged in.

How would one go about such a script if it is possible?

Once again, if somebody logs in on a site that is on one server, is it possible to create a script that will alert the (same domain and same site) other server, so when this logged in person goes to that page the html will be changed because they are logged in.

Comment: If your question is _if it is possible?_ then yes, yes it is.

Comment: I don't think it can be done on server-side, as PHP script processes only what was sent within request. The only - slight - option is to use Referrer field, but it can be easily spoofed.

Comment: @j08691 the question is *"How would one go about such a script if it is possible?"*

Answer (score 1):

You could try using database driven session, and then probably some if statements with database querying?

For more details you could start here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php